# Deploy dotnet core application using dotnetcore in windows machines

Tags: deployment, asp.net-core

I am trying to deploy published dotnet core project in other windows machines in which dotnet sdk is installed using dotnet run

I am getting error [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LFMhU.png)

Anyone help me to resolve this.

Comment: Which version of dot net core you're using? Are you using project.json or CSProj?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For published projects you should use `dotnet myapp.dll` (where myapp.dll is the name of your application dll) and not `dotnet run`